# Java serialization (of an X509CertificateObject)

Tags: java, serialization, apache-commons, bouncycastle, x509

I'm trying to serialize and de-serialize a Bouncy Castle `X509CertificateObject` using `org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils`.
Apparently the de-serialized object is of a different type (`sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl`) than the originally serialized object (`org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject`). Consequently casting fails.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void test(X509CertificateObject certObj) {
    byte[] serializedObj;
    Object deSerializedObj;
    X509CertificateObject deSerializedCertObj;
    X509Certificate deSerializedCert;

    System.out.println("certObj type: " + certObj.getClass().getName());
    serializedObj = SerializationUtils.serialize(certObj);
    deSerializedObj = SerializationUtils.deserialize(serializedObj);
    System.out.println("deSerializedObj type: " + deSerializedObj.getClass().getName());
    deSerializedCert = (X509Certificate) deSerializedObj;
    System.out.println("deSerializedCert type: " + deSerializedCert.getClass().getName());
    deSerializedCertObj = (X509CertificateObject) deSerializedObj;
    System.out.println("deSerializedCertObj type: " + deSerializedCertObj.getClass().getName());
}
```

results in:

```
certObj type: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject
deSerializedObj type: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
deSerializedCert type: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
```

and finally in

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject
at Test.test(Test.java:1010)
at Test.main(Test.java:153)
```

Is this because the upper class of `X509CertificateObject`, which is `X509Certificate`, is abstract and/or because `X509CertificateObject` does not define its own `serialVersionUID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround/solution.
The Java serialization problem seems to be due to a conflict between BC and Java JCE.
I'm now using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) in connection with [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public static byte[] serializeToXML(Object obj, XStream xStreamConfig)
    throws Exception
{
    XStream xstream;
    String certObjString;
    byte[] certObjByte;

    if(xStreamConfig == null) {
        xstream = new XStream();
    } else {
        xstream = xStreamConfig;
    }

    certObjString = xstream.toXML(obj);

    certObjByte = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(certObjString);

    return certObjByte;
}

public static Object deserializeFromXML(byte[] objectByteArray, XStream xStreamConfig)
{
    String objectString;
    Object object;
    XStream xstream;

    if(xStreamConfig == null) {
        xstream = new XStream();
    } else {
        xstream = xStreamConfig;
    }

    objectString = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(objectByteArray);

    object = xstream.fromXML(objectString);

    return object;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem was that wasn't solved by using X509Certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Just cast to `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`, which all those other classes should extend. You certainly shouldn't be expecting or using `sun.*` classes.

Comment: He is neither expecting nor using a `sun.*` class. He is just getting one on deserialization.

Comment: For testing I inserted a cast to X509Certificate.
This cast is successful, however the type of the casted Object is still sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.
I'm puzzled how this can happen and further on why this is possible and casting to X509CertificateObject on the contrary fails.

Comment: @ThomasLieven So X509CertImpl extends X509Certificate. No mystery there. X509CertificateObject would extend it as well. But xxxImpl doesn't extend xxxObject, or vice versa.